# Mixed model assumptions of linearity

Tags: r, mixed-model, data-transformation, assumptions

I want to use a mixed model to analyse the association of distance covered per minute (TD_min) with ball possession (phase), playing position (role). Data have been recorded for the same subjects during multiple matches.
The model is below

```
TD_model1 <- lmer(TD_min ~ phase + role + (1|player), data = data, REML = FALSE)
```

Now I am trying to check the assumptions following https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter18.html
For linearity, I am doing

```
plot(resid(TD_model1), data$TD_min)
```

and for normality of resudials am doing

```
qqmath(TD_model1)
```

In both cases the assumptions do not hold. Now here is the problem.
If I do inverse transformation

```
TD_model2 <- lmer(1/(max(TD_min+1) - TD_min) ~ phase + role + (1|player), data = data, REML = FALSE)
```

I get the error message **boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular**

If I do log transofmration

```
TD_model3 <- lmer(log10(max(TD_min+1) - TD_min) ~ phase + role + (1|player), data = data, REML = FALSE)
```

The assumptions don't hold
[image]

The same for normality of residuals
[image]

I already removed a random effect from the model, so can't make it any simpler.

What can I do?

THanks

Comment: I suppose for your inverse transform, you will just divide by 0 in some instances which then creates NA's or Infs which makes the model fail (I might be wrong). Why do you want to make the model simpler when the assumptions do not hold?

Comment: TD_min does not have 0 values. I thought the issue of singular fit was caused by having too much effects in the model, therefore I removed one effect but did not help.
What could be the issue?

Comment: I would say the problem must be in the transform since your other models fit. Anyway, to check linearity, you should have residuals on the y axis and predicted variables on the x-axis, or individual predictors on the x-axis, so not the actual target variable